# Как сверстать перетаскивание и загрузку файла как на макете

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, drag-n-drop

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сверстать такой макет? Или какой плагин можно использовать? Какой плагин легче кастомизировать под такой макет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте https://www.dropzonejs.com/

Насколько я понимаю из контекста - это макет формы обратной связи. Данный плагин позволит вам реализовать функционал `<input type="file" name="file" />` без лишней головной боли.

Вот тут подробно описано про кастомизацию под нужный внешний вид: 
https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/How-to-theme-Dropzone

Если кратко - там просто html файл, который вы меняете как вам надо.